# Unable to set column names to a subset of a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, r-colnames

I run the following code, `p` is the dataframe loaded.

```
a <- sort(table(p$Title))
a1 <- as.data.frame(a)
tail(a1, 7)

                     a
Maths               732
Science             737
Physics             737
Chemistry           776
Social Science      905
null              57374
                  88117
```

I want to do some manipulations on the above dataframe result. I want to add column names to the dataframe. I tried the colnames function.

```
colnames(a1) <- c("category", "count")
```

I get the below error:

```
Error in `colnames<-`(`*tmp*`, value = c("category", "count")) : 
    attempt to set 'colnames' on an object with less than two dimensions
```

Please suggest.

Comment: I think your first column are from above are rownames

Comment: the class(a1) is data.frame

Comment: As @Jaap said, it seems you have row names there. Try `a1$category <- row.names(a1)` maybe (unless it was a typo as @Richard suggests)

Comment: @RichardScriven  Here is what I tried.                                       colnames(a1)<-data.frame("category", "count")
Error in `colnames<-`(`*tmp*`, value = list(X.category. = 1L, X.count. = 1L)) : 
  'names' attribute [2] must be the same length as the vector [1]

Comment: Yeah, you need to shift the row names into a column, as mentioned above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I said in the comments to your question, the categories are rownames. A reproducible example:

```
# create dataframe p
x <- c("Maths","Science","Physics","Chemistry","Social Science","Languages","Economics","History")
set.seed(1)
p <- data.frame(title=sample(x, 100, replace=TRUE), y="some arbitrary value")

# create the data.frame as you did
a <- sort(table(p$title))
a1 <- as.data.frame(a)
```

The resulting dataframe:

```
> a1
                a
Social Science  6
Maths           9
History        10
Science        11
Physics        12
Languages      15
Economics      17
Chemistry      20
```

Looking at the dimensions of dataframe `a1`, you get this:

```
> dim(a1)
[1] 8 1
```

which means that your dataframe has 8 rows and 1 column. Trying to assign two columnnames to the `a1` dataframe will hence result in an error.

You can solve your problem in two ways:

**1**: assign just 1 columnname with `colnames(a1) <- c("count")`

**2**: convert the rownames to a category column and then assign the columnnames:

```
a1$category <- row.names(a1)
colnames(a1) <- c("count","category")
```

The resulting dataframe:

```
> a1
               count       category
Social Science     6 Social Science
Maths              9          Maths
History           10        History
Science           11        Science
Physics           12        Physics
Languages         15      Languages
Economics         17      Economics
Chemistry         20      Chemistry
```

You can remove the rownames with `rownames(a1) <- NULL`. This gives:

```
> a1

  count       category
1     6 Social Science
2     9          Maths
3    10        History
4    11        Science
5    12        Physics
6    15      Languages
7    17      Economics
8    20      Chemistry
```